# How to receive a file from ActiveMQ using Camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I have sent a file "file.txt" to a Queue "A"   as blob message. I want to receive that "file.txt" to  my local folder "D:/output".

I tried the following code . bUt no use..

```
     CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
     ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false");

     context.addComponent("test-jms",
                JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory));
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from("test-jms:queue:A").to("C:/output");
            }
        });
```

Please help me..

Thanks Arun

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the Apache Camel [File2 Component](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html)

The endpoint format is `file:directory?options`

So in your case:

```
from("test-jms:queue:A").to("file:C:/output");
```

Have a read through the various options on the component and see if they are relevant.